# How do i convert 0.099 to 0.1 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to convert the number 0.099 to 0.1 but if i use Math.ceil or Math.round it gives me 0 instead of 0.1.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
var n2 = Math.round(n1*10)/10;
```

That supposes you really want another number and not a string. If you want to format your number as a string do

```
var s = n1.toFixed(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Math.ceil((0.099*10))/10` if you always want to round it up.
So `Math.ceil((0.049*10))/10` also becomes 0.1

Answer (score 0):

A generic way to do round decimals:

> Number((.099).toFixed(1));

Parameter to toFixed is the `number of decimal places` you want. Please note toFixed returns a String, which I have converted back to Number.